# Google Wallet: loading FullWallet only works after changing MaskedWallet

Tags: android, android-pay

I'm implementing Google Wallet into an Android app and running across a strange issue.

I can load the MaskedWallet request just fine, but when I'm ready to place an order and attempt to load the FullWallet, I receive an ERROR_CODE_INVALID_PARAMETERS error response. However, if I immediately call the `changeMaskedWallet` method afterwards, then make an identical FullWalletRequest as in my first attempt, the FullWallet comes down just fine.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

**Edit:**
My code to create the FullWalletRequest looks like this:

```
return FullWalletRequest.newBuilder()
            .setGoogleTransactionId(googleTransactionId)
            .setCart(Cart.newBuilder()
                    .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                    .setTotalPrice(String.format("%.2f", totalPrice))
                    .setLineItems(buildLineItems(cartModel))
                    .build())
            .build();
```

When I call `changeMaskedWallet`, I receive the same googleTransactionId and pass it through to this builder. Also, I tried adding the merchant transaction Id, but that didn't help. Unfortunately, I cannot post the logic to generate line items but I essentially use the `LineItem.newBuilder()` builder to create each item I need to add.

Comment: Any code snippet to illustrate your problem?

Comment: @Fred: thanks, I posted what I'm allowed to. Any help would be great!

Comment: There should be an error in the logcat which tells you why exactly the request failed such as invalid currency, or invalid line item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I wasn't setting the line items correctly, though it's very hard to tell as there are no errors logged to LogCat. I instead used Gson to serialize the Wallet object and inspected the resulting Json by eye. Not the best approach, but it worked for me.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what was wrong with your line items? I'm running into something similar...

Comment: I figured my situation out... I was using the test Stripe key instead of the live one.